# Automatic export of abstract to separate text file

Tags: macros, pdftex, abstract, export

Lets assume we want to write an article. A third party asks us to submit the abstract as a text file.

Can I automatically export the abstract of a LaTeX document to a text file? Ideally, the abbreviations or other LaTeX macros are expanded before export.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\newcommand{\texttest}{TEST}
\newacronym{BLSTM}{BLSTM}{bidirectional long short term memory network}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract \texttest~with interesting abbreviations like \gls{BLSTM} and other macros like $\SI{15}{\second}$.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Expected output:

```
This is an abstract TEST with interesting abbreviations like bidirectional long short term memory network (BLSTM) and other macros like 15 s.
```

Comment: I think it would be better to look for a pdf or dvi converter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must to maintain the `\abstractdefs` macro where special definitions are in order to expand to the desired output. The example below shows what you need to insert to the `\abstractdefs` in order to realize your example above. Moreover, there is a `\stipdollars` macro which removes dollars from the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[acronym, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\newwrite\absfile
\NewEnviron{Abstract}{
   \immediate\openout\absfile=\jobname.abs
   \begingroup
      \def\tmp{}\abstractdefs 
      \expandafter\stripdollars\BODY$\relax
      \immediate\write\absfile{\tmp}%
   \endgroup
   \abstract\BODY\endabstract
}
\long\def\stripdollars#1${\edef\tmp{\tmp#1}\stripdollarsA}
\def\stripdollarsA{\futurelet\next\stripdollarsB}
\def\stripdollarsB{\ifx\next\relax\else \expandafter\stripdollars\fi}

\def\abstractdefs{
   \def~{ }
   \def\gls##1{##1}
   \def\SI##1##2{##1 ##2}
   \def\second{s}
   \def\par{^^J}
   \def\TeX{TeX}
}

\newcommand{\texttest}{TEST}
\newacronym{BLSTM}{BLSTM}{bidirectional long short term memory network}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Abstract}
This is an abstract \texttest~with interesting abbreviations like \gls{BLSTM} 
\end{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works very well. Can you elaborate why `\def\par{^^J}` avoids `\par` to appearch in the output file?

Comment: ^J (input as ^^J here) is the ASCII line feed control character, so \par is effectively replaced by a newline character. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a package that does this and having all commands in the abstract expand to plain text is probably not possible because latex is not designed to turn commands into plain text.

Here is a solution that writes your abstract to a file, expanding "what it can". It uses the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package to define a new `Abstract` environment and the [newfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfile) package to write the abstract to a file and "expand" the abstract in some sense. Using the the `Abstract` envinment the abstract appears as it normally does in the PDF file and a partially expanded version of the abstract is written to `\jobname.abs` (that is, the name of the LaTeX file with an `abs` extension. For the abstract in the original file, this produces the following `abs` file:

> This is an abstract TEST\nobreakspace {}with interesting abbreviations like \gls {BLSTM} and other macros like $\SI {15}{\second }$.

So, some expansion has occurred but there is a cost with primitives like `\nobreakspace` appearing in the output together with `\gls` and `\SI` commands. I do not know how to do better than this.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage[acronym, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

\newoutputstream{abstract}% define a new output file stream
\NewEnviron{Abstract}{
  \openoutputfile{\jobname.abs}{abstract}% open the abs file
  \addtostream{abstract}{\BODY}% write the abstract=\BODY to the file
  \closeoutputstream{abstract}%  close the file
  \abstract\BODY\endabstract%    add the abstract to the PDF file
}

\newcommand{\texttest}{TEST}
\newacronym{BLSTM}{BLSTM}{bidirectional long short term memory network}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Abstract}
This is an abstract \texttest~with interesting abbreviations like \gls{BLSTM} and other macros like $\SI{15}{\second}$.
\end{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can likely be accomplished using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html), as described in a couple of [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341899/latex-to-markdown-converter) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180369).

You should be able to do something like:

```
pandoc -s example.tex -o /dev/stdout | grep -P abstract -A 2
```

I have not been able to try this yet, but will update this answer if I get the opportunity to do so.